# new line from asp to json and back with jquery

Tags: jquery, vbscript, asp-classic

I have an .asp file that converts data from database to json. problem is when new line symbol occurs. When calling file for json, i am getting:

> "Error: Parse error on line 1: --json code sample--  Expecting
>   'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '['"

over a place when new line is.
My question is there any way to fix it without changing code in json receiving end of program. And be able to fill aps form fields with data from json using jquery and keeping new lines intact.

I was trying to replace `vbcr`, `vbcrlf` to `\n`, `\ \ n`, `\ \ \ \n`, nothing helps.

I hope i explained it clear enough.

UPDATE
Its clasic ASP VBSCIPT.
(source.asp -> json -> dest.asp using jquery to parse json and put data to form fields.)
everything works ok, unless there is new line symbol "cr fl" somewhere in DATA that source.asp is making json from. Then json data is used by dest.asp and jquery is filling dest.asp form fields with json data. problem is that json seems to not recognize vbCrLf symbol placed by vb script to mark new line. If i am replacing it with "" in source.asp, everything works, but then i cannot keep line breaks in dest.asp and i am wondering is there is any way to fix/hack it without changing code in dest.asp

Comment: I am still confused not sure about others. Can you post your generated json here?

Comment: Is this classic asp or asp.net? And you need to show some code, where you are parsing, and a sample json.

Comment: Sorry, but can't, sensitive data. Tbh now i see that this error is generated by chrome extension called "JSONView" so it might have been a bit missleading info. Let me update my question a bit.

Answer (score 0):

please download the this picture  from the link

http://uupload.ir/files/vir8_capture.jpg

if you used the \n may be you code is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

If you're unwilling to show the source code and the data that caused the issue, then our ability to analyse the problem is limited. However, I can offer another suggestion.

If you're using some kind of homebrew code to parse/format JSON which is choking on simple characters like line-breaks, then you might want to consider using something else that's been tried and tested by hundreds of people. This one I'm providing is a class called VBSJson and has two public functions called Encode (turn a VBScript variable, array or dictionary into JSON) and Decode (convert JSON into VBScript native values). It's served our team well for 2 years and it's well-documented.

```
<%

    Class VbsJson
        ' Author: Demon
        ' Date: 2012/5/3
        ' Website: http://demon.tw/my-work/vbs-json.html
        Private Whitespace, NumberRegex, StringChunk
        Private b, f, r, n, t

        Private Sub Class_Initialize
            Whitespace = " " & vbTab & vbCr & vbLf
            b = ChrW(8)
            f = vbFormFeed
            r = vbCr
            n = vbLf
            t = vbTab

            Set NumberRegex = New RegExp
            NumberRegex.Pattern = "(-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*))(\.\d+)?([eE][-+]?\d+)?"
            NumberRegex.Global = False
            NumberRegex.MultiLine = True
            NumberRegex.IgnoreCase = True

            Set StringChunk = New RegExp
            StringChunk.Pattern = "([\s\S]*?)([""\\\x00-\x1f])"
            StringChunk.Global = False
            StringChunk.MultiLine = True
            StringChunk.IgnoreCase = True
        End Sub

        ' Return a JSON string representation of a VBScript data structure
        ' Supports the following objects and types
        ' +-------------------+---------------+
        ' | VBScript          | JSON          |
        ' +===================+===============+
        ' | Dictionary        | object        |
        ' | Array             | array         |
        ' | String            | string        |
        ' | Number            | number        |
        ' | True              | true          |
        ' | False             | false         |
        ' | Null              | null          |
        ' +-------------------+---------------+
        Public Function Encode(ByRef obj)
            Dim buf, i, c, g
            Set buf = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            Select Case VarType(obj)
                Case vbNull
                    buf.Add buf.Count, "null"
                Case vbBoolean
                    If obj Then
                        buf.Add buf.Count, "true"
                    Else
                        buf.Add buf.Count, "false"
                    End If
                Case vbInteger, vbLong, vbSingle, vbDouble
                    buf.Add buf.Count, obj
                Case vbString
                    buf.Add buf.Count, """"
                    For i = 1 To Len(obj)
                        c = Mid(obj, i, 1)
                        Select Case c
                            Case """" buf.Add buf.Count, "\"""
                            Case "\"  buf.Add buf.Count, "\\"
                            Case "/"  buf.Add buf.Count, "/"
                            Case b    buf.Add buf.Count, "\b"
                            Case f    buf.Add buf.Count, "\f"
                            Case r    buf.Add buf.Count, "\r"
                            Case n    buf.Add buf.Count, "\n"
                            Case t    buf.Add buf.Count, "\t"
                            Case Else
                                If AscW(c) >= 0 And AscW(c) <= 31 Then
                                    c = Right("0" & Hex(AscW(c)), 2)
                                    buf.Add buf.Count, "\u00" & c
                                Else
                                    buf.Add buf.Count, c
                                End If
                        End Select
                    Next
                    buf.Add buf.Count, """"
                Case vbArray + vbVariant
                    g = True
                    buf.Add buf.Count, "["
                    For Each i In obj
                        If g Then g = False Else buf.Add buf.Count, ","
                        buf.Add buf.Count, Encode(i)
                    Next
                    buf.Add buf.Count, "]"
                Case vbObject
                    If TypeName(obj) = "Dictionary" Then
                        g = True
                        buf.Add buf.Count, "{"
                        For Each i In obj
                            If g Then g = False Else buf.Add buf.Count, ","
                            buf.Add buf.Count, """" & i & """" & ":" & Encode(obj(i))
                        Next
                        buf.Add buf.Count, "}"
                    Else
                        Err.Raise 8732,,"None dictionary object"
                    End If
                Case Else
                    buf.Add buf.Count, """" & CStr(obj) & """"
            End Select
            Encode = Join(buf.Items, "")
        End Function

        ' Return the VBScript representation of ``str(``
        ' Performs the following translations in decoding
        ' +---------------+-------------------+
        ' | JSON          | VBScript          |
        ' +===============+===================+
        ' | object        | Dictionary        |
        ' | array         | Array             |
        ' | string        | String            |
        ' | number        | Double            |
        ' | true          | True              |
        ' | false         | False             |
        ' | null          | Null              |
        ' +---------------+-------------------+
        Public Function Decode(ByRef str)
            Dim idx
            idx = SkipWhitespace(str, 1)

            If Mid(str, idx, 1) = "{" Then
                Set Decode = ScanOnce(str, 1)
            Else
                Decode = ScanOnce(str, 1)
            End If
        End Function

        Private Function ScanOnce(ByRef str, ByRef idx)
            Dim c, ms

            idx = SkipWhitespace(str, idx)
            c = Mid(str, idx, 1)

            If c = "{" Then
                idx = idx + 1
                Set ScanOnce = ParseObject(str, idx)
                Exit Function
            ElseIf c = "[" Then
                idx = idx + 1
                ScanOnce = ParseArray(str, idx)
                Exit Function
            ElseIf c = """" Then
                idx = idx + 1
                ScanOnce = ParseString(str, idx)
                Exit Function
            ElseIf c = "n" And StrComp("null", Mid(str, idx, 4)) = 0 Then
                idx = idx + 4
                ScanOnce = Null
                Exit Function
            ElseIf c = "t" And StrComp("true", Mid(str, idx, 4)) = 0 Then
                idx = idx + 4
                ScanOnce = True
                Exit Function
            ElseIf c = "f" And StrComp("false", Mid(str, idx, 5)) = 0 Then
                idx = idx + 5
                ScanOnce = False
                Exit Function
            End If

            Set ms = NumberRegex.Execute(Mid(str, idx))
            If ms.Count = 1 Then
                idx = idx + ms(0).Length
                ScanOnce = CDbl(ms(0))
                Exit Function
            End If

            Err.Raise 8732,,"No JSON object could be ScanOnced"
        End Function

        Private Function ParseObject(ByRef str, ByRef idx)
            Dim c, key, value
            Set ParseObject = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            idx = SkipWhitespace(str, idx)
            c = Mid(str, idx, 1)

            If c = "}" Then
                Exit Function
            ElseIf c <> """" Then
                Err.Raise 8732,,"Expecting property name"
            End If

            idx = idx + 1

            Do
                key = ParseString(str, idx)

                idx = SkipWhitespace(str, idx)
                If Mid(str, idx, 1) <> ":" Then
                    Err.Raise 8732,,"Expecting : delimiter"
                End If

                idx = SkipWhitespace(str, idx + 1)
                If Mid(str, idx, 1) = "{" Then
                    Set value = ScanOnce(str, idx)
                Else
                    value = ScanOnce(str, idx)
                End If
                ParseObject.Add key, value

                idx = SkipWhitespace(str, idx)
                c = Mid(str, idx, 1)
                If c = "}" Then
                    Exit Do
                ElseIf c <> "," Then
                    Err.Raise 8732,,"Expecting , delimiter. Got " & c & " at " & idx
                End If

                idx = SkipWhitespace(str, idx + 1)
                c = Mid(str, idx, 1)
                If c <> """" Then
                    Err.Raise 8732,,"Expecting property name"
                End If

                idx = idx + 1
            Loop

            idx = idx + 1
        End Function

        Private Function ParseArray(ByRef str, ByRef idx)
            Dim c, values, value
            Set values = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            idx = SkipWhitespace(str, idx)
            c = Mid(str, idx, 1)

            If c = "]" Then
                idx = idx + 1
                ParseArray = values.Items
                Exit Function
            End If

            Do
                idx = SkipWhitespace(str, idx)
                If Mid(str, idx, 1) = "{" Then
                    Set value = ScanOnce(str, idx)
                Else
                    value = ScanOnce(str, idx)
                End If
                values.Add values.Count, value

                idx = SkipWhitespace(str, idx)
                c = Mid(str, idx, 1)
                If c = "]" Then
                    Exit Do
                ElseIf c <> "," Then
                    Err.Raise 8732,,"Expecting , delimiter"
                End If

                idx = idx + 1
            Loop

            idx = idx + 1
            ParseArray = values.Items
        End Function

        Private Function ParseString(ByRef str, ByRef idx)
            Dim chunks, content, terminator, ms, esc, char
            Set chunks = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

            Do
                Set ms = StringChunk.Execute(Mid(str, idx))
                If ms.Count = 0 Then
                    Err.Raise 8732,,"Unterminated string starting"
                End If

                content = ms(0).Submatches(0)
                terminator = ms(0).Submatches(1)
                If Len(content) > 0 Then
                    chunks.Add chunks.Count, content
                End If

                idx = idx + ms(0).Length

                If terminator = """" Then
                    Exit Do
                ElseIf terminator <> "\" Then
                    Err.Raise 8732,,"Invalid control character"
                End If

                esc = Mid(str, idx, 1)

                If esc <> "u" Then
                    Select Case esc
                        Case """" char = """"
                        Case "\"  char = "\"
                        Case "/"  char = "/"
                        Case "b"  char = b
                        Case "f"  char = f
                        Case "n"  char = n
                        Case "r"  char = r
                        Case "t"  char = t
                        Case Else Err.Raise 8732,,"Invalid escape"
                    End Select
                    idx = idx + 1
                Else
                    char = ChrW("&H" & Mid(str, idx + 1, 4))
                    idx = idx + 5
                End If

                chunks.Add chunks.Count, char
            Loop

            ParseString = Join(chunks.Items, "")
        End Function

        Private Function SkipWhitespace(ByRef str, ByVal idx)
            Do While idx <= Len(str) And _
                InStr(Whitespace, Mid(str, idx, 1)) > 0
                idx = idx + 1
            Loop
            SkipWhitespace = idx
        End Function

    End Class

%>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I've found was brought by [JsonConverter](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON) module.
After installing following instructions You have to parse your string using `json=JsonConverter.ParseJson(your_string)` and then `JsonConverter.ConvertToJson(json)`.